# How do I put multiple criterias to a boolan statement on python jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make pyton pick out all the passengers that survied, among them if they are female, and within that find what class they are.

i can only fit jsut one criteria, but I cannot get them to select even 2 criterias I have set.

I am a complete beginnger so I have no idea how to format it

I also got this error below:

> IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

for putting this:

```
surv_titanic = titan_sub['survived'] ==1
titan_sub[titan_sub[surv_titanic]['sex']== 'female']
```

I got the error:

> IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

basically the `titan_sub` contains all the columns I have needed, all the survived, being female, and I didnt event get to the class part yet, but it is in that subset too

Please help

Comment: You have too many levels of nesting. Just use `titan_sub[surv_titanic]['sex']`. `surv_titanic` was already created from `titan_sub`, you don't have to specify it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple filter conditions using parentheses to create more complex filtering logic. Logical operators such as `&` (and), `|` (or), and `~` (not) can be applied to the conditions.

```py
titan_sub[(titan_sub["Survived"] == 1) & (titan_sub["Sex"] == "female")]
```

Alternatively you could use the `query()` method.

```py
titan_sub.query("Survived == 1 & Sex == 'female'")
```